# Get Table Rows with Pagination

Tags: eosjs, multi-index, table, rpc

How do we get records from a table by pages?

My requirement: I have a table with 100 records and want to display all these records in my front-end-application with 10 records per page and if the user hits the 'Next'-button, the records from the next page (e.g 11 to 20, 21 to 30 etc.) have to be queried.

Likewise when hitting the 'Prev'-button, the previous 10 records have to queried. How can I implement this logic using EOSJS's(V20.0.0) and the get_table_rows()-endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

This has its limitations but if you are fetching a table by the primary key which is an incremented integer value, you could use a combination of `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, and `limit` and do something like this:

```
// base setup
var pageSize = 10
var curLower = 0
var curUpper = pageSize - 1
// fetch first page
fetchRows(curLower, curUpper, pageSize) 

// next btn click
handleNext(curLower, curUpper, pageSize) {
  curLower = curUpper + 1
  curUpper += pageSize
  const res = fetchRows(curLower, curUpper, pageSize)
  if(res.rows.length < pageSize) {
    curUpper = curLower + res.rows.length - 1
    // handle last page
  }
}

// prev btn click
handlePrev(curLower, curUpper, pageSize) {
  curUpper = curLower - 1
  curLower -= pageSize
  const res = fetchRows(curLower, curUpper, pageSize)
  if(curLower == 0) {
    // handle first page
  }
}

async fetchRows(lower, upper, pageSize) {
  const res = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,              
    code: <my_contract>,     
    scope: <my_scope>,         
    table: <my_table>,        
    limit: pageSize,               
    reverse: false,         
    lower_bound: lower,
    upper_bound: upper
  })
  return res
}
```

Needs more handling for stuff like `res.rows.length < pageSize` in first page, handling of results that aren't first/last page... but you get the point.

Comment: But then how to show the total number of pages?

Answer (score 0):

Typo in code example above on these lines:

```
    reverse = false,         
    lower_bound = lower,
    upper_bound = upper 
                ^- Not valid JSON - replace = with :
```