# Fetching More Table Rows via RPC

Tags: multi-index, table, get-table

I have a contract with a table in it.  I'm querying the contents of the table using the RPC interface, but I'm having trouble getting all the rows.  To limit the memory usage of my application, I'm only retrieving a limited number of rows for call.  The result indicates that there are more rows, but I need to send in a new lower bound value to get the next set of results.

How do I determine what value to use for the lower bound to get the next set of results?  In this particular case, I don't know which of the columns in the result contain the primary key value.

It's too bad that the response from the server that indicates that there are more results doesn't include the value to use for the lower bound on the subsequent query.  After all, the node knows what column it is querying against.

I found this [similar question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/get-table-rows-with-pagination), but it doesn't have any answers.